# parseFloat as parse function not allowing decimal

Tags: redux-form

I have a need to maintain my value as a float. So I gave my field this parser:

```
export const parseDecimal = value => value ? parseFloat(value) : value;
export const formatNumber = value => typeof value === 'number' ? value.toString() : value; // <TextInput> freaks out with string
```

I use it in my field like this:

```
<Field name="decimal" parse={parseDecimal} format={formatNumber} />
```

I have to use `formateNumber`, which makes the number into a string because I am using react-native and the `<TextInput>` element only works with strings.

However anytime I hit the `.` to write a decimal it gets blocked/removed. Is there anyway to allow a decimal but continuously `parseFloat` it?

Comment: In your parseDecimal, why don't you convert value to a string, and if it contains a decimal symbol, append a 0 to the rightmost of the decimal?

Comment: @AyushGupta thanks for the idea but when I do that, and if the user wanted to type `1.4` they will keep getting `1.0` and can never put `4` :(

Comment: Try this: `export const parseDecimal = value => parseFloat(value) && !Number(value) && value.endsWith('.')? value: parseFloat(value);`

Comment: Thanks @AyushGupta! however that makes it not a number in the redux store which messing stuff up. Is there a way to make `parse` store (based on form name and field name) that the next `format` should not format as number but as decimal?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with redux. But can't you apply the logic of my first comment while storing it in the store and of my last comment while the user enters it?

Comment: Or simply do another parseFloat before inserting it into the store

Comment: @AyushGupta I can't do that because then it gets stored into the redux store as a string and places are expecting a number. I would have to go through and change all those instance to also deal with a string :( I really appreciate your discussion here!

Comment: No I mean parseFloat it just before you save it into the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use next method:

```
export const parseDecimal = value => {
  return !parseFloat(value) || !Number(value) || value.endsWith('.') ? value : parseFloat(value);
};
```

And how it used:

```
<Field
    name={'crop_capacity'}
    placeholder={'Урожайность (ц/га)'}
    parse={(value) => parseDecimal(value)}
    component={InputAdapter}
/>
```

Thanks to @Ayush Gupta comment above.

Comment: Thank you for sharing!!